# Py2exe; Import Error no module named Tweepy

Tags: python, compilation, py2exe, tweepy, setup.py

My python script includes a Qt GUI which I'm trying to convert into a Windows executable using Py2exe. My script is using the Tweepy module to fetch data from Twitter. So I include Tweepy and try to compile it into an executable using the following Setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows = [{"script": "main.py"}],
    options = {"py2exe":{"includes":["sip", "tweepy"]}}
    )
```

The following Error gets raised:

```
raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

I've succesfully used the same setup file (minus the 'Tweepy include') to compile other script in the past. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have tweepy **installed** in the python installation that you are trying to build with try adding:

```
import tweepy
```

near the start of your setup.py to ensure that py2exe can really see it, some packages do some interesting things during import.

Comment: Steve.. You are a god.

Comment: @Loops No - I have just hit this type of problem before!